# Grouping dataframes by periods with tidyverse

Tags: r, time, tidyverse

I have a data table with 3 variables :

- Individual IDs
- Number of days after a measure is done
- value of the measure.

I need to group these values according to the day they are made : if no new measure is done since 5 days, that's a new group.

I wrote the code below, it's OK but not very efficient since it's time consuming and my data are very large (more than 1 million rows).

Is there a more efficient way to do that ?

Thanks for helping

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

set.seed(50)

data <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10), rep("C",10)),
                 day = round(runif(30, min = 0, max = 100),0),
                 value =  runif(30, min = 100, max = 150)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, day)


head(data)
#  ID day    value
# 1  A  30 144.1148
# 2  A  31 113.5508
# 3  A  41 111.3492
# 4  A  48 121.1822
# 5  A  60 101.8316
# 6  A  64 113.6760

data2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff = day - lag(day)) %>% 
  mutate(diff2 = ifelse(is.na(diff), 100, diff)
                         )  %>% 
  mutate(NewSeq = ifelse(diff2 <6, FALSE, TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(IDSeq = ifelse(NewSeq, day, NA )) %>% 
  mutate(IDSeq = zoo::na.locf(IDSeq)) %>%
  mutate(IDSeq = dense_rank(IDSeq)) 

> data2
# A tibble: 30 × 7
# Groups:   ID [3]
   ID      day value  diff diff2 NewSeq IDSeq
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  <int>
 1 A        30  144.    NA   100 TRUE       1
 2 A        31  114.     1     1 FALSE      1
 3 A        41  111.    10    10 TRUE       2
 4 A        48  121.     7     7 TRUE       3
 5 A        60  102.    12    12 TRUE       4
 6 A        64  114.     4     4 FALSE      4
 7 A        72  121.     8     8 TRUE       5
 8 A        76  141.     4     4 FALSE      5
 9 A        83  137.     7     7 TRUE       6
10 A        99  126.    16    16 TRUE       7
# … with 20 more rows

data2 %>% 
  group_by(IDSeq, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
            n = n(), 
            .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 21 × 4
   ID    IDSeq value     n
   <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
 1 A         1  129.     2
 2 A         2  111.     1
 3 A         3  121.     1
 4 A         4  108.     2
 5 A         5  131.     2
 6 A         6  137.     1
 7 A         7  126.     1
 8 B         1  142.     1
 9 B         2  129.     2
10 B         3  124.     1
# … with 11 more rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `cumsum()` on the "NewSeq" column, and to use a single call of `mutate()`:

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(diff = day - lag(day),
         NewSeq = ifelse(!is.na(diff) & diff < 6, FALSE, TRUE),
         IDSeq = cumsum(NewSeq))
```

Comment: Excellent idea ! Using the cumsum function decreases processing time. Thank you so much